# Is this a standard Perl language construction or a customization: open HANDLE, ">$fname"

Tags: perl, error-handling, file-io

Not a Perl guru, working with an ancient script, ran into a construct I didn't recognize that yields results I don't expect. Curious whether this is the standard language, or a PM customization of sorts:

```
open FILE1, ">./$disk_file" or die "Can't open file: $disk_file: $?";
```

From the looks of this, file is to be opened for writing, but the log error says that file is not found. Perl's file i/o expects 3 parameters, not 2. Log doesn't have the die output, instead saying: "File  not found"

Confused a bit here.

EDIT: Made it work using the answers below. Seemed like I was running a cashed version of the .pl for some time, instead of the newly-edited. Finally it caught up with a 2-param open, thanks y'all for your help!

Comment: You need to look into [Learning Perl, Chapter 10](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/learn/ch10_02.htm) where this construction is described. Nowadays similar construction is written in modern style as `open my $fh, '>', $disk_file or die "Can't open file: $disk_file: $?";`.

Answer (score 4):

That is the old 2-argument form of open.  The second argument is a bit magical:

- if it starts with `'>'` the remainder of the string is used as the name of a file to open for writing
- if it starts with `'<'` the remainder of the string is used as the name of a file to open for reading (this is the default if '<' is omitted)
- if it ends with `'|'` the string up to that point is interpreted as a command which is executed with its STDOUT connected to a pipe which your script will open for reading
- if it starts with `'|'` the string after that point is interpreted as a command which is executed with its STDIN connected to a pipe which your script will open for writing
  This is a potentially security vulnerability because if your script accepts a filename as user input, the user can add a `'|'` at the beginning or end to trick your script into running a command.

The 3-argument form of `open` was added in (I think) version 5.8 so it has been a standard part of Perl for a very long time.

The `FILE1` part is known as a bareword filehandle - which is a global. Modern style would be to use a lexical scalar like `my $file1` instead.

Answer (score 3):

See [perldoc perlopen](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for details but, in brief...

Perl's `open()` will accept either two or three parameters (there's even a one-parameter version - which no-one ever uses). The two-parameter version is a slightly older style where the open mode and the filename are joined together in the second parameter.

So what you have is equivalent to:

```
open FILE1, '>', "./$disk_file" or die "Can't open file: $disk_file: $?";
```

A couple of other points.

1. We prefer to use lexical variables as filehandles these days (so, `open my $file1, ...` instead of `open FILE1, ...`).
2. I think you'll find that `$!` will be more useful in the error message than `$?`. `$?` contains the error from a child process, but there's no child process here.

**Update:** And none of this seems to be causing the problems that you're seeing. That seems to be caused by a file actually not being in the expected place. Can you please edit your question to add the exact error message that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are correct that's the two-argument syntax. They've done a good job covering why and how you should ideally change it, so I won't rehash here.

However they haven't tried to help you fix it, so let me try that...

This is a guess, but I suspect `$disk_file` contains a filename with a path (eg `my_logs/somelog.log`), and the directory part (`my_logs` in my entirely guessed example) doesn't exists, so is throwing an error. You could create that directory, or alter whatever sets that variable so it's writing to a location that does exist.

Bear in mind these paths will be relative to wherever you're running the script from - *not* relative to the script itself, so if there's a log directory (or whatever) in the same dir as the script you may want to `cd` to the script's dir first.